# Recursively flatten an object

Tags: python, object, recursion

I have the following object:

```
d={
   'CollectionTitleIDs': {
           '852070#TVEpisode': '12', 
           '852063#TVEpisode': '4', 
           '852067#TVEpisode': '9'
     }, 
    'ReleaseYear': '2005', 
    'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'
}
```

I would like to flatten it to get the following output:

```
{
   'CollectionTitleIDs': [
      {"_Key": "852070#TVEpisode", "Value": "12"},
      {"_Key": "852063#TVEpisode", "Value": "4"},
      {"_Key": "852067#TVEpisode", "Value": "9"}
    ]
    'ReleaseYear': '2005', 
    'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'
}
```

In other words, if the value of the key is a dict, to push the keys of that dict to a "_Key" field and the value of that to a "Value" field.

I've been having difficulty with the recursion. And currently I have something like this:

What I currently have is:

```
def flatten_obj(obj, FLAT_OBJ=None):

    if FLAT_OBJ is None: FLAT_OBJ = OrderedDict()
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [flatten_obj(l, FLAT_OBJ=FLAT_OBJ) for l in obj]
    elif not isinstance(obj, dict):
        return obj
    else:
        for key in list(obj.keys()):
            val = get_sub_object_from_path(obj, key)
            if isinstance(val, dict):
                FLAT_OBJ[key] = [{'_Key': subkey, 'Value': flatten_obj(subval)} for subkey, subval in val.items()]
            elif isinstance(val, list):
                FLAT_OBJ[key] = flatten_obj(val, FLAT_OBJ=FLAT_OBJ)
            else:
                FLAT_OBJ[key] = val
    return FLAT_OBJ
```

Note that the above has one level of recursion, but it's possible the "value" will have a(nother) nested object as well, in which case we want to again extract the _Key,Value.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the comment with some code? You even mention recursion, but don't have anything recursive.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, please see updated question with example.

Comment: So what's the *problem* with what you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be simpler than that:

1. If it's a list return the list of flattened objects
2. If it's a dict return a list of the key/val objects
3. otherwise just return x

in code:

```
def flatten1(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [flatten1(y) for y in x]
    elif isinstance(x, dict):
        return [{"_Key": key, "Value": flatten1(value)}
                for key, value in x.items()]
    else:
        return x
```

In your example however for some reason the **toplevel** is not being flattened and is instead a regular dict, then just do so

```
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
       return {key: flatten1(value) for key, value in x.items()}
    else:
       return flatten1(x)
```

`flatten1` could even be made an internal function:

```
def flatten(x):
    def flatten1(x):
        if isinstance(x, list):
            return [flatten1(y) for y in x]
        elif isinstance(x, dict):
            return [{"_Key": key, "Value": flatten1(value)}
                    for key, value in x.items()]
        else:
            return x

    if isinstance(x, dict):
       return {key: flatten1(value) for key, value in x.items()}
    else:
       return flatten1(x)
```

Comment: thanks this is really helpful and what i was looking for. Could you please clarify why you would need to use `flatten` vs `flatten2`? I'm not quite clear on that.

Comment: You just call `flatten`; then flatten calls `flatten1`. This is needed because the way you want to process dictionaries is different for the first one (why the outer one is not an array with `{"_Key":,.., "Value":...}` like other dicts?).

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. The only change I made is to make it an `OrderedDict` instead of a regular one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking with a list comprehension:

```
d = {'CollectionTitleIDs': {'852070#TVEpisode': '12', '852063#TVEpisode': '4', '852067#TVEpisode': '9'}, 'ReleaseYear': '2005', 'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'}
new_d = {**d, 'CollectionTitleIDs':[{'_Key':a, 'Value':b} for a, b in d['CollectionTitleIDs'].items()]}
```

Output:

```
{'CollectionTitleIDs': 
  [{'_Key': '852070#TVEpisode', 'Value': '12'}, 
   {'_Key': '852063#TVEpisode', 'Value': '4'}, 
   {'_Key': '852067#TVEpisode', 'Value': '9'}], 
 'ReleaseYear': '2005', 'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Method:

```
d={
   'CollectionTitleIDs': {
           '852070#TVEpisode': '12', 
           '852063#TVEpisode': '4', 
           '852067#TVEpisode': '9'
     }, 
    'ReleaseYear': '2005', 
    'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'
}

d['CollectionTitleIDs'] = list(map(lambda x: {'_Key': x[0], 'Value': x[1]}, d['CollectionTitleIDs'].items()))

#{
#  'CollectionTitleIDs': [
#    {'_Key': '852070#TVEpisode', 'Value': '12'},
#    {'_Key': '852063#TVEpisode', 'Value': '4'}, 
#    {'_Key': '852067#TVEpisode', 'Value': '9'}
#  ], 
#  'ReleaseYear': '2005', 
#  'TVSeriesID': '5638#TVSeries'
#}
```